# What happens behind-the-scenes when I create a new UIImage by assignment?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uikit, uiimage

I am getting errors of type EXC-BAD-ACCESS where I create a new UIImage instance by assigning the value of a pre-existing UIImage (as below) and I am trying to figure out what the problem is. There is a heap of code to sort through and I am not sure where to start so I won't bother posting source -- but it might help me in my investigation of any of you could tell me **What exactly is going on (memory-wise) when I create a new UIImage by assigning from another?**

```
(in the .h)

UIImage* myExistsImage;

...

@property (retain) UIImage* myExistsImage;

...

-(UIImage*)rotateImage:(UIImage*)imageToRotate;



----------------------------------------------------


(in the .m)
@synthesize myExistsImage;

...

UIImage* myNewImage = [self rotateImage:myExistsImage];


...

-(UIImage*)rotateImage:(UIImage*)imageToRotate
{

UIImage* rotatedImage = imageToRotate;

//Rotate Image Here (details omitted)...

 return rotatedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIImage* rotatedImage = imageToRotate;
```

In that line, you're not creating a new UIImage object; you're simply creating a new pointer to the old one.  If `Rotate Image Here` implies in-place modifications to `rotatedImage`, then you're actually modifying `myExistsImage` as well.

If you want to create a new UIImage object to hold the rotated object, you'll need to explicitly do so with the UIImage `alloc` and `init` methods.

Comment: Oh. So since it is just a pointer, if the actual image data it points gets released then this might be the cause of my EXC-BAD-ACCESS correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  If you want the data to remain until both pointers are done, just add a retain when you copy the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

With code like:

```
UIImage* src;
UIImage* dst = src;
```

... all you're doing is copying a pointer. In order to make sure that `dst` and `src` are going to keep pointing to a valid `UIImage` you need to call `retain` on the `UIImage` twice -- once for `src` and once for `dst`. When you no longer need a pointer, you should call `release` on the `UIImage`- when all the pointers have gone away the last call to `release` will deallocate the `UIImage`. What you're seeing is that the `UIImage` is being released while you're still interested in using it; you need to `retain` it, then, to keep that from happening.